# Request doesn't hit port 80 on HAproxy

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I'm configuring HAProxy to redirect http to https, but it doesn't seem to work. The configuration I use is:

`/etc/hosts` content

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

Haproxy configuration

```
frontend http
  mode http
  bind :80
  bind :443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/
  redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }

  default_backend my_backend
```

Testing with curl give this error

```
$ curl https://example.com < this works 
$ curl http://example.com 
> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 2400:cb00:2048:1::681c:a20: No route to host
```

However, command `lsof` has output

```
$ sudo lsof -i :80 | grep LISTEN
haproxy   7290 root    4u  IPv4 0x9485b36892b5495d      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

I'm out of idea what's wrong in this situation. This is the first time I configure SSL on Haproxy.

Comment: @masegaloeh thanks for pointing out. You are correct, but when I try to connect via ipv4, I has this `curl: (7) couldn't connect to host`

Comment: what version of haproxy are you running?

Comment: @JimG. The HAproxy version I use is : HA-Proxy version 1.5.3 2014/07/25

Comment: Do you get an error on http in a browser?

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar set up in HAProxy which works. I can only find two differences between your configuration and mine.

1. In `/etc/hosts` I have bound `example.com` to `0.0.0.0` rather than `127.0.0.1`.
2. In my frontend, both `bind` entries contain a wildcard (`*`) in front of the colon. Example:

   ```
   bind *:80
   bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/ssl.pem
   ```

   2a. I actually used a pem file in my configuration (as above) but seeing as `curl https://example.com` worked it is unlikely this is the problem.

I would also suggest looking at the output of `netstat -tulpn | grep haproxy` for more detail on where HAProxy is binding.

Hope that helps.